# Vmware asking for gcc 9.4.0 while i have 11.3.0

Tags: vmware, gcc, 22.10, vmware-player

[image: screenshot of problem]

VMware requires GCC version 9.4.0 to be installed on the system, but the available GCC version on the Ubuntu 22.10 system is 11.3.0.

Comment: An older version of Ubuntu would run the 9.4 You need to look into what is asking for this older version.